# Determining the Geoid model used by GPS receiver

Tags: gps, wgs84, nmea

I have the following NMEA output by Holux M-241 GPS receiver:

```
$GPGGA,144014.000,2227.0987,N,11410.1382,E,2,6,1.67,32.6,M,-1.3,M,0000,0000*7B
```

I know that WGS84 height is higher than Geoid height 1.3 meter. But how can I know that which Geoid model it is using?

Also, is it a database stored in the GPS chip for Geoid height and WGS84 height conversion?

Comment: by default, the GPS height is usually given relatively to WGS 84. What makes you think this is not the case here ?

Comment: In the above NMEA response, there are two heights. One is ellipsoid height, which is the height you mentioned. One is geoid height, which is calculated from a function of coordinates and ellipsoid height. What I mean is the geoid height.

Comment: > To call WGS 84 simply an ellipsoid isn’t quite accurate. The WGS 84 GPS systems we use have a geoid component as well. The present WGS 84 system uses the 1996 Earth Gravitational Model (EGM96) geoid and is the best-fitting ellipsoid to the geoid model for the selected survey points in the set. (Obe & Hsu, Post GIS in Action, p. 157)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what geoid model is used, or how is the undulation being calculated.

In the  [Global Positioning System Fix Data section of the NMEA sentence information page](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga), it is described as *Height of geoid above WGS84 ellipsoid*, without specifying what geoid model is being used.

But the codification of the geographic coordinates lets us to ask the [online calculation of geoid undulations based in the GeoidEval utility of GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeoidEval?input=22d27.0987%27N+114d10.1382%27E&option=Submit), which returns:

```
Geoid height:

    lat lon = 22.45164 114.16897 (22°27'06"N 114°10'08"E)
    geoid heights (m)
        EGM2008 = -2.5657
        EGM96   = -2.3861
        EGM84   = -1.9314
```